# Implementing horizontal sharding in Spring Boot project

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a project which uses Spring Boot with Spring Data JPA to store data in a MySQL instance. Now my data is growing at a rapid rate. I searched and found some text regarding horizontal sharding of data. But Spring Boot has setting to connect with only one of the instances of the DB how it is possible to implement horizontal sharding in that case?

Also, I have one-to-many relationship between 2 tables. how will this horizontal sharding work in that case?

Comment: Expand your question.... Not enough details. Honestly, quite surprised still using Spring Boot when you're talking about Database Sharding technologies.

Comment: @MichaelCropper yes question is same is while using springboot DB sharding is possible?

Comment: There was an interesting pod about sharding with MySQL recently: https://www.se-radio.net/2023/04/se-radio-560-sugu-sougoumarane-on-distributed-sql-with-vitess/

Answer (score 0):

You don't offer much detail in your question, probably because you are at the beginning of your research, so the answer can only be general as well.

Let's start by making sure we are talking about the same:
Horizontal sharding is the process of distributing your data to different databases. Something has to direct each query to the correct shards for this to work. For example if you shard by customer and customer A is put on shard 1 you won't be able to find it when you query shard 2.

In general with this kind of thing you have two options:

1. do the sharding logic in your application
2. do the sharding logic outside the application.

With the second approach the sharding would be transparent to the application, it would just get a normal JDBC URL to connect to and behind that URL is some kind of process that distributes queries.

With the first approach the application itself has to decide which shard to address.
The Spring based tool for this is a [`AbstractRoutingDatasource`](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-abstract-routing-data-source).
Exactly how to do this depends on your data, sharding strategy and many more.

> I have one-to-many relationship between 2 tables. how will this horizontal sharding work in that case?

One-to-many relationships aren't much of a problem. Just make sure that the many-side gets distributed to the same shard as the one-side.
So if you have a `purchase-order` and `order-item`s the `order-items` of the `purchase-order` must end up on the same shard.

More challenging are M-to-N relationships. Say you have `purchase-order` and product. Of course the M-to-N relationship breaks down into two 1-M relationships. But if you now try to apply the principle from above you have two independent sharding rules for `order-item`.
The trick here is to break one of the relationships and for the other one just have an id instead of a Java reference. You then would use a separate query to query using the id of the product and for that go again through your sharding layer.

This is actually what you do when breaking down your domain model based on the principals of Domain Driven Design. [I wrote about this in the context of Spring Data JDBC](https://spring.io/blog/2018/09/24/spring-data-jdbc-references-and-aggregates). But it applies just as well to your use case.
Actually moving towards Spring Data JDBC might be an option for you since it enforces these kinds of constraints from the get go.

There is another challenge you should start thinking about and that is resharding. When your data grows you probably want to eventually break up shards into new shards, which is a none-trivial thing to do.